# Finding 1st order & 2nd order partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given $v = p(a)$ and $a = q(t,u)$.

How do I find $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial t^2}$?

I am thinking of the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= p'(a)\times q'_t(t,u)\\
\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial t^2} &= p''(a)\times \begin{bmatrix}q'_t(t,u)\end{bmatrix}^2 + p'(a)\times q''_{tt}(t,u)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: In the second derivative, $q'_t(t,u)$ should be squared. Otherwise I think this is right, assuming that $t$ and $u$ are independent.

Comment: Hello @alex.jordan I added to make it $q''$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, the second derivative should be $p''(a)\cdot\left(q_t(t,u)\right)^2+p'(a)\cdot q_{tt}(t,u)$.

Comment: Oh...chain rule...I think I get it...how about now?

Comment: Well, your simultaneous use of primes and subscripts, as in $q'_{tt}$, is a little confusing. But yes, it's all just the chain rule and the product rule (still assuming that $t$ and $u$ are independent variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the community, the solution is verified that it is correct.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could guide me on what happens if my problem has been solved without any answers? I have a few that were like this. For this one, there are no answers but it was solved by helpful members who wrote in the comments.

Comment: You could ask the person who wrote the best comment to add an answer and to give credit to other commentators if so needed - so we can have accepted answers if you agree to accept it, for example. You can also answer your question yourself and do the same, for example.

Comment: Typically I ans my own questions. Afterwhich, I will accept my own answer 2 days later as the minimum waiting time for me to accept my own answer is 2 days.

Comment: I get answering your own question. I made it CW to show that it was part community effort, though.

Comment: sorry, but i do not understand what "i made it CW..." means :/